I'm having trouble understanding why IDEA shows the source file as .java
For example, when I want to view the source code of a class, like Thread, and I use Ctrl + Click to navigate to it, it displays Thread.java. However, I don't understand why this is the case. Isn't the JDK packaged in JAR files like rt.jar, which should mainly contain .class files rather than .java files?
So why do I see Thread.java when I Ctrl + Click, instead of Thread.class?
Additionally, I searched my entire disk for Thread.java, but I couldn't find this file anywhere.

This is because IDEA default decompiler decompile the class. On top of the decompile file showes .. the name of decompiler like FrenFlower decompiler.
IDEA also provide the ribbon to download the source file on top of the editor.
Once source is downloaded then source can be found in local repository.
